# Building a machine: can I flash BIOS without a processor?

Tags: bios, computer-building

My media server is giving up the ghost after a few good years and I'm prepping to build a new one. I'm looking at the Shuttle SN78SH7 barebones box with a AMD Phenom II processor. Compatible sockets, but comments on NewEgg and the manufacturer's website suggest the motherboard BIOS does not support the Phenom II out of box, but requires an update to the latest version.

The question is, will I be able to flash the BIOS with no processor socketed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot flash it directly but you can always take chip out and use Willem style programmer (e.g. [Shivava](http://www.sivava.com/)).

However, you may try to run standard flashing it anyhow. Quite often you can boot up BIOS flash program even with "unsupported" processor. It would not work for any complicated stuff (Windows, Linux) but BIOS flashing might just work.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, BIOS flash is an operation involving the processor.

Comment: Not if you have a separate hardware programmer handy.